# Persistent Filters: And operation in filters when using Or

Tags: haskell, persistent

Persistent has an OR filter `||.` but it does not seem to have a corresponding `&&.`  I would like to do something like `A && (B || C) && (D || E)` and I am not sure the cleanest way to do it.

I guess I can create all combinations like `(A && B && D) || (A && C && D) || (A && B && E) || (A && C && E)`.  It gets quite unwieldy even for this simple example. Not sure if there is a better way to do this with `persistent`.

The code compiles when I do (inside `selectList`) `[A] ++ ([B] ||. [C]), etc.` but not sure if it is equivalent to what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Pragmatically speaking, you can write a [**`QuickCheck`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) property to determine if the `persistent` boolean expression is equivalent to the normalized boolean expression.

Comment: @recursion.ninja. Good point. I have not used QuickCheck with DB-oriented functions before. That said, I can probably manually setup a table with all boolean combinations of `A-E` and see if my `selectList` works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`++`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) or [`<>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:-60--62-) to and lists of filters together.

From the [Persistent manual](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent):

> ```
> people <- selectList [PersonAge >. 25, PersonAge <=. 30] []
> liftIO $ print people
> ```
>
> The list of filters is `AND`ed together, so that our constraint means "age is greater than 25 AND age is less than or equal to 30". We’ll describe ORing later.

Comment: Thanks Cirdec. I have not had a chance to test it but it seems like this is the  way to combine ANDing OR groups. I think it will be cleaner if `&&.` was provided as a convenience function so people have to figure out if the order of parens will matter or not. I will add this as a feature request.